# Running multiple inserts into an Oracle table, how can I commit after each insert and restart the stored procedure at the last inserted point?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm very new to Oracle and am writing my first stored procedure for a side project. Essentially I have one table for intraday data, and another table to store historical data. I need to insert chunks of the intraday table into the history table, commit those inserts, and restart the stored procedure at the first uninserted point in the case of failure.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 5000)
IS
TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF z_intraday%ROWTYPE;
l_data ARRAY;

CURSOR c IS SELECT *
FROM "intraday";

BEGIN
   OPEN c;
   LOOP
   FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT p_array_size;

   FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
   INSERT INTO history
   VALUES l_data(i);

   EXIT WHEN c%notfound
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;

   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;

   CLOSE c;
END test_proc;
```

So I only commit after the loop has finished. How can I refactor so that each insert operation in the loop commits, then if there is a failure, roll back to the previous batch of records that failed and run the procedure again? Sorry I know this is a heavy question, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a side comment.  FROM "intraday"   You have written your table name in lower-case, and wrapped it in double-quotes, indicating that you have created the name in lower-case and making it case sensitive.  In oracle you should _never_ create an object name with double-quotes around the name.  Doing so makes the name case-sensitive and you will forever have to deal with it accordingly.  Leave the double-quotes for the MSSql crowd, and enjoy oracle's case-INsensitive naming.

Answer (score 2):

Use set-based operations wherever possible, not row-by-row operations. A single "insert as select" or "merge" statement with filter would run faster by several orders of magnitude than the row-by-slow construct you have created. Also, committing after every individual row will kill your performance for the entire database instance, not just this procedure, as it forces checkpoints in the redo logs.

```
insert into history (col1, col2, col3) 
   as select col1, col2, col3 from intraday d
   where d.id not in (select id from history);
commit;
```

or

```
merge into history h
   using intraday d
   on (h.id = d.id)
   when not matched then
      insert (h.id, h.col2, h.col3) values (d.id, d.col2, d.col3);
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a complicated procedure, you can use `INSERT INTO ... LOG ERRORS INTO ...` to capture the errors and then all the errors can be put into one table and the valid rows will all be successfully inserted (continuing on from each error, if you specify `REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED`).

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "intraday" (
  a INT PRIMARY KEY,
  b DATE,
  c TIMESTAMP,
  d VARCHAR2(30),
  e VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TABLE history (
  a INT,
  b DATE,
  c TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  d VARCHAR2(30),
  e DATE
);

INSERT INTO "intraday"
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-01', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'valid', '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-01-02', NULL, 'timestamp null', '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-01-03', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-03 00:00:00', 'implicit date cast fails', '2020-01-XX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2020-01-04', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-04 00:00:00', 'valid', '2020-01-04' FROM DUAL;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Then you can create a table to put the errors using:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG (
    dml_table_name     => 'HISTORY',
    err_log_table_name => 'HISTORY_ERRORS'
  );
END;
/
```

Then you can run the SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO history
SELECT * FROM "intraday"
LOG ERRORS INTO history_errors ('INSERT APPEND')  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Then the history table will contain:

```sql
SELECT * FROM history;
```

> ```
>  A | B          | C                         | D     | E         
> -: | :--------- | :------------------------ | :---- | :---------
>  1 | 2020-01-01 | 01-JAN-20 00.00.00.000000 | valid | 2020-01-01
>  4 | 2020-01-04 | 04-JAN-20 00.00.00.000000 | valid | 2020-01-04
> ```

And the errors will be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM history_errors;
```

> ```
> ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ | ORA_ERR_MESG$                                                                        | ORA_ERR_ROWID$ | ORA_ERR_OPTYP$ | ORA_ERR_TAG$  | A  | B          | C                            | D                        | E         
> --------------: | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------- | :------------- | :------------ | :- | :--------- | :--------------------------- | :----------------------- | :---------
>            1400 | ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FIDDLE_HSUKHKSUNFGTKKAMLHOA"."HISTORY"."C")<br> | null           | I              | INSERT APPEND | 2  | 2020-01-02 | null                         | timestamp null           | 2020-01-01
>            1858 | ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected<br>        | null           | I              | INSERT APPEND | 3  | 2020-01-03 | 03-JAN-20 00.00.00.000000000 | implicit date cast fails | 2020-01-XX
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3bfeeb2f1722c5dd3cd4f0c5c248b04)*